# 2 download click button with same class using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to click on 2 download buttons with same button class. below is the code

```
file=driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root IconButton-sc-iv40hv-1 cLszZl IconButton-sc-iv40hv-0 hbJxSM DownloadButton-sc-19l7ggt-0 gHtfyl MuiIconButton-colorPrimary'])")


driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", file)
```

this works only for 1st button..

2nd button if add 2nd file with index val 2... only second button works

I need to click on both download buttons one after another..

Comment: maybe use `find_elements` with char `s` at the end to get list with all matching elements - and later use `[1]` to work with second element on list.

Comment: do you get error or what? Show it in question because we can't run this code, we can't see this page and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: after clicking it may change content in browser's memory and you may have to use again `find_element` to search again elements in browser's memory.

Comment: something definitely changed... coz getting to the new tab and browsing the same URL.. and then find_element (with index val 2) works for 2nd button..Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get the specific button try with class and index OR try with text and index whichever you comfortable.

Example you have 2 buttons like this

**Button 1 :**

```
<button class="expedition_button awesome-button " onclick="attack(null, '2', 1, 0, '')">Attack</button>
```

**Button 2 :**

```
<button class="expedition_button awesome-button " onclick="attack(null, '2', 2, 0, '')">Attack</button>
```

you can finish with this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[text()[contains(.,'Attack')]])[indexval]") 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='expedition_button awesome-button '])[indexval]")
```

And then Similar for Button 2 , 3 & 4 just increase the index value.

**For Button1:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[text()[contains(.,'Attack')]])[1]")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='expedition_button awesome-button '])[1]")
```